# Is it possible to enable Chrome Remote desktop on a computer so that someone who walks up to it cannot read your mail

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

If you want a computer at the office to be accessible to you when you're at home, can you enable Google Remote Desktop on it but at the same not have it so that someone could walk up to the machine and run gmail and see your mail? In other words, do you have to be logged in to Google for Chrome Remote Desktop to work  on that machine?

Comment: Are you allowed to remote into your work computer from your home computer? Wouldn't your work computer have to be locked after at least some period of inactivity?

Comment: Yes, before leaving the office I would ctrl-alt-del to bring up the lock screen, but if I forgot to do that, say, it would come up automatically after a set time.  But once I remote in, the lock screen goes away and whatever I'm working on becomes visible to passers-by.  The Google mechanism for blanking out the screen (editing the registry) didn't work.

Comment: As an IT professional, what you are saying makes me VERY concerned for security, both for the reasons you state (people seeing your screen in the office) and for many, many other reasons. If there is an approved remote method, your local IT will be able to provide this for you. You do not own that computer, and you are not allowed to decide what happens on it: that is the privilege and responsibility of your employer. If they require you to work remotely, they can and will provide the means to do so within their security requirements.

Comment: Also: Rather than pressing CTRL-ALT-DEL to lock your computer, press Windows-L. It's quicker, simpler, and easier.